# "Proposed Method" in Academic Paper

Tags: academic-writing

Is it okay to use the term "proposed method" in academic paper if I already done implementing the method? Or what phrase I can replace to this?

Answer (score 1):

No. If the experiment is already completed, you would list what you did under the **Materials and Methods** part of your paper. You may editorialize at the end of the section, but it is best to propose detailed changes in the **Discussion** section. If your completed experiment did not offer the conclusion you were hoping for, that's where (**Conclusion**) you could add what you would do next time to make it better, in brief.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's okay because it's a method that you are *proposing* to the readers. So you can write

> The method proposed in this paper allows [...]

or

> We have therefore shown that the proposed method yields [...]